# Meaning of "I shut my eyes to hold my breath"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, figures-of-speech, lyrics

From the folk song Oh! Susanna by Stephen Foster (presumably written in slave dialect):

> De bullgine bust, de hoss ran off, I really thought I’d die;
> **I shut my eyes to hold my bref**—Susanna, dont you cry.

[Sheet music from Duke University on Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Oh!_Susanna_4.jpg)

Emphasis mine. What does this phrase mean? All searches of that phrase and its variations turn up lyrics to Oh! Susanna, which makes me wonder if this phrase is unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything.  The lyrics are deliberate nonsense, full of contradictions.

Consider :

> It rained all night the day I left, the weather it was dry;
> The sun so hot I froze to death—Susanna, don’t you cry.

The weather is both rainy AND dry. A contradiction.  The sun was hot, but the singer froze. Another contradiction.

> I jumped aboard the telegraph and traveled down the river,

How is it possible to travel on a telegraph?  It isn't possible, it's nonsense.

> I shut my eyes to hold my breath

There is no connection between shutting eyes and holding breath. It's a non-sequitur. Another piece of nonsense.  It doesn't mean anything, and that's the joke.

Comment: The older song “Nottamun Town” has similar nonsense: “I called for a quaff [=drink] to drive gladness away / To stifle the dust for it rained the whole day.”

Comment: @AntonSherwood is there a term for this kind of non-sequitur in lyrics?

Comment: @forest Yes, it's called 'absurd' or 'nonsense'.

Comment: @Mitch I meant a term specific to the lyrical technique. I take it you mean there is none?

Comment: I think the adjective 'absurd' and noun 'nonsense' are what are used for description. I don't think 'nonsense poetry' is a set phrase for the genre. So it would be well understood, but linguistically it is not a category. There is ['nonsense poetry'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonsense_verse) which does not make it a set phrase/linguistic category though it might be considered a category. There they mention ['amphigory'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amphigory) which seems to be archaic (and of questionable provenance - it is not used nowadays).

Comment: @forest: The rhetorical device — whether in lyrics or prose — is called *paradox*: a statement that is self-contradictory.